# “heroku run rails db: migrate” (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, require

I am in the last steps of the Railsbridge Installfest process and everything has gone smoothly until I reach the Deploy (push) to Heroku and type "heroku run rails db: migrate" this is supposed to be the expected message:

```
Migrating to CreateDrinks (20160706063236)
==  20160706063236 CreateDrinks: migrating =====================================
-- create_table(:drinks)
   -> 0.0084s
==  20160706063236 CreateDrinks: migrated (0.0085s) ============================

And this is the message I get instead:


 Running rails db:migrate on ⬢ immense-coast-99385... up, run.5688 (Free)
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError) from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:inrequire'
from /app/bin/spring:8:in <top (required)>' from /app/bin/rails:3:inload'
from /app/bin/rails:3:in `'
```

Also, when I type

> Heroku open

the app won't start.

Comment: Have you a database created on heroku ?

Comment: Yes I did, but its still showing me the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Hi, It's seems that it can't find your bundler 
 - update your bundler (gem install bundler or gem update bundler) 
 - update your gem (bundle update better to update one by one) 
 - commit and push again

Hope its help !